# How to pass data from a node.js server to Apache served PHP page?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, socket.io

I am trying to build a node.js chat feature for an existing PHP project. I am using node.js socket.io for it. Node.js is listening to port 3000. Now the problem is when I try to access the chat PHP page http://www.example.com:3000/app/chat.php the page gets downloaded instead of being served. I know that node.js does not serves PHP pages but what workaround can be done for the same?

Node.js

```
var app = require('express')(),
        server = require('http').createServer(app),
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
        httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('send data',function (data) {
                io.sockets.emit('latest data',data);           
        });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

// Blah Blah

<script>
                        jQuery(function($))
                        {
                                var socket = io.connect();
                                var $editArea = $('#editAreaID');

                                $editArea.keydown(function(){
                                        socket.emit('send data', $editArea.val());
                                });

                                socket.on('latest data', function(data){
                                        $editArea.val(data);
                                });
                        }
</script>

// Blah Blah

?>
```

Comment: can you post the code please

Comment: Isn't Apache running on `www.example.com/app/chat.php` ? And why would you need PHP anyway if you're using node for the chat?

Comment: Server side -> http://pastebin.com/DQR7jP8P
Client side -> http://pastebin.com/icigaBgk

Comment: Apache is running www.example.com/app/chat.php but since nodejs and apache both are running on server so I made nodejs to listen to different port i.e. 3000.

Comment: So you want both servers on the same port? That doesn't make much sense. Why?

Comment: No. I don't want both servers to run on same port. I was just not able to figure out how can I make node.js send data to chat.php. I need PHP because it is an already existing PHP project in which I am integrating node.js chat .

Comment: `exec` from "child_process" let's you run processes, so you can execute `php index.php arguments` from node, where `arguments` represents your data ($argv in php)

Comment: Its been 1 year @Siddharth :D I am facing same problem did u managed node.js send data to .php ?

Comment: and how did you managed this http://www.example.com:3000/app/chat.php ?? I mean port `3000` is for `nodejs` and how did u mixed with apache?

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg It was an year back and I do not exactly remember what I did then. But reading the question now it is clear to me that I was doing wrong :) I should not try to serve a php page with Node.js . Say apache runs on default port 80 and nodejs is running on port 3000, then from your PHP page simple make requests to www.example.com:3000/app and do your stuff. I do not know if this makes sense to you but please ask if you have doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP page is being downloaded instead of running normally then it has probably nothing to do with the node.js server.

Verify first that PHP is installed correctly and that the PHP module is enabled in the apache configuration.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally